# Vmware Workstation 10 connect remote server (Debian, Guest-Windows XP) Does not allow raw disk access nor shared folders

Tags: linux, windows-xp, vmware, remote-connection

The setup:

Ubuntu with local Vmware Workstation 10 (everything works locally)

[image: http://zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-310114-232132.php]

Connects(File-> Connect to Server) Debian server with the same Vmware Workstation 10 (Windows XP Guest)

Debian setup does not allow raw disk access nor shared folders (most options does not exist)

[image: http://zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-310114-231804.php -]
No shared folder

[image: zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-310114-232827.php -] No physical disk option

I use root user for this machine. Default install.

I've tried to add shared folder from command line - it does not work.

How to enable shared folders or raw disk access?

I have created new Windows 8 64 bit template from scratch - I cannot use physical HDD either, and no SharedFolder option. I think this is something about security policy of remote server.

Comment: There's not a lot of information in your question.  Are you trying to map an XP guest to a physical disk running on a Linux machine?  If so if the physical disk is not in a format that Windows can recognize then most likely that is why it is not allowed.  Without more information it's hard to say.  Please provide more details when you can.

Comment: Again, not a lot of information to go on.  Explain your setup in more detail please.  What do you mean by remote server?  Are you connecting via VNC to another physical host that has Workstation on it trying to manage a vm?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Alright, those screenshots do not have any information regarding the disks.  In order to use a physical disk you have to have a separate partition available to the guest operating system.  This could be a separate hard drive or partition on the host disk but it must be dedicated to the guest.  Please see the documentation below:
http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-2A1F74A4-A5F3-4090-9A45-396D6D407CE5.html#GUID-2A1F74A4-A5F3-4090-9A45-396D6D407CE5

Comment: In regards to the Shared Folder option not being available, please make sure you've followed these steps and have the latest VMWare Tools installed on the guest:  
http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html

Comment: According to VMWare, Debian is not in the supported Host OS list for Workstation 10:
http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&testConfig=17

Comment: I've never had problems with Debian host before. I really think that it is the security limitation, because remote user can attach any HDD or local directory to compromise security. But i cannot find proof.

Comment: If it isn't in the supported OS list then the behavior of the software is not guaranteed.  It may work on one device one way and differently on another.  Sorry to say but if it isn't in the supported OS list, there is most likely a reason.